# Load a dll from an external source

Tags: c#

How can I load a dll from a website without having to have the user have it pre-downloaded on their PC.

My scenario is: they run my program, they don't have the dll, program retrieves the dll, continues to run normally.

But wouldn't the program crash before it gets the dll?

Comment: Have you considered just running a portion of your program that doesn't require the dll and checks if the user has it? Either that or just write a start-up check that runs your main program if it has the dlls it needs.

Comment: Are you writing a plugin-style system? If so, look at [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), or similar for dynamically loading plugins. If your main-program *requires* this DLL for basic functionality - I think you'll need to explain what your requirements are in a bit more detail!

Comment: Maybe you could do something with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` and when it doesn't find the dll it's looking for, try to auto-download it from the website and retry?

Comment: You could do this, but life would be simpler if you'd delegate the responsibility to the installer.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that make this process easy, the one I have used is [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) by Microsoft. What you will need to do is turn that DLL in to a "Module", then tell Prism to download the module when it is needed.

If you download their samples they have a "[Modularity QuickStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068(v=pandp.40).aspx)" and in that sample there is a "Downloading modules in the background" section which you can see how to do exactly what you want to do.